# I am facing problem: the superclass "jakarta.servlet.http.httpservlet" was not found on the java build path

Tags: javascript, html

I have installed all necessary files but still it is throwing error.

I have gone through help<install new software<then selected site<next<next<I accept..... all is done then also showing the superclass "jakarta.servlet.http.httpservlet" was not found on the java build path

Answer (score 0):

Try project **Clean and rebuild**.

If you are using Maven for your project, make sure that the **correct version** of the Servlet API is specified in your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```